# Return a custom error Response from WebApi without throwing Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I would like to return a custom Response (ProblemJson) from my asp.net web api controller, but before the method of the controller itself gets executed. Given a controller that looks like this:

```
[Put]
[Route("api/{userId}")]
public User UpdateUser(Guid userId, [FromBody] user)  
{
     .... 
}
```

and i call the api with this

```
api/thisIsNoGuid
```

Then WebApi answers with a default error message that I would like to change so it fits with our other error messages with is a defined ProblemJson. Right now we generate these ProblemDocuments by throwing exceptions and catching them in the WebApi filters that generate the ProblemDocument for us. I could make the Guid nullable and throw an exception if the Guid is null, so our filters do the work, but I do not think that this is a good idea, as it will be forgotten and then the api is inconsistent.

I want to avoid code like this:

```
[Put]
[Route("api/{userId}")]
public User UpdateUser(Guid userId, [FromBody] user)  
{
     if (userId == null) return new Error()
     .... 
}
```

So what I would like is something like the ExceptionFilters where you can override the `OnException` method to create your own response but for error cases that happen before the request reaches the controller. Is it possible to override the default behaviour of WebApi like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this yes, and you're close when you mention `ExceptionFilter`s, because you actually handle this case using a custom `ActionFilter`. Something like this:

```
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

public class InterceptBadRequestFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // whatever your condition is
        if (...)
        {
            var response = actionContext
                .Request
                .CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Custom error message");

            actionContext.Response = response;
        }
    }
}
```

There is an `OnActionExecutingAsync` method you can override as well, if you need that.

Comment: Ok thanks, this seems like the thing that I would need. But I would have to go over the request via reflection, right? If I do this like a filter and make this for every request would that not decrease performance only to handel some few edgcases? Implementing the IActionFilter and iterating over the ActionParameters is the way to go, right? Will try this tomorrow, thanks allready =)

Comment: @Simons0n It depends on how complex your case is (i.e. do you really need reflection, or is this just to handle odd cases?). By that I mean, if you're only really looking for id-type properties, like `userId` in your example, there's no reason not to just use the attribute via [InterceptBadRequestFilter("userId")] and look for the offending item using that key. Anything more than that, and it's really a case of profiling to see. Just remember you don't have to register it globally, and it's perfecly fine to have separate filters performing similar logic if performance is that important.

Answer (score -1):

For custom errors, use IHttpActionResult type:

```
[Put]
[Route("api/{userId}")] 
public IHttpActionResult UpdateUser(Guid userId, [FromBody] user)  
{
     if (userId == null) 
     {
       var message = "Sorry, this is not a valid GUID";
       HttpError err = new HttpError(message);
       return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, err));
     }

    . . .
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: That is right, i know how to return a custom error message, but I want to do it automatically before the controller

Comment: @Simons0n you  can use delagate handler for this